# How can I decide if the body is stopped(sleeping)

Tags: c++, box2d

There is a moving BOX2D body, how can I  decide if the body is stopped(sleeping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is documentation for all of the functions in the header files:

```
 /// Get the sleeping state of this body.
 /// @return true if the body is sleeping.
     bool IsAwake() const;
```

Usage:

```
body->IsAwake();
```

Source: http://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Dynamics/b2Body.h